# Get Id of table row if it is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a datatable containing a list of Cars.  each row in the html contains a Car ID.  I have added checkbox column to the first cell in my datatable - if it is checked the row is highligted to indicate to the user they have selected that row.  What I waht to do is get all the IDs of all the cars a user has selected on clicking a button on the page.  (also there are other columns in the table row where I have checkboxes (i.e - a Manual column or an Automatic column which will somtime be checked - like in column 5 ot 6 in the table)

so this is part of the cshtml for my page..

```
@foreach (var car in Model.Cars)
{
    <tr carId="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.CarID)">
       <td class="table-data">
            <input id="SelectIndividual" name="Select" type="checkbox" />
        </td>

//more stuff set in other tds in table
```

Then this is the JS I have for the page so far.

```
$('#GetSelectedCars').click(function (event) {

    var cars= new Array();

    carsListTable.find("tr").each(function (index, para) {

        $('tr').find('td:input:checked:first').each(function () {
            var car= new Object();
            alert($(this).parent().parent().attr("carId"));
            car.ID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("carId");
            cars.push(car);
        });

    });

    var jsonString = $.toJSON(cars);
```

I want to then return the json string to my controller (I do this by passing the value into a hidden field on my model and then deserialize - but at the minute I am getting it as empty.  My problem is getting the best way to get the id from the row if it is checked?

Comment: careful with `carId`, use `id` or `data-carId` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the selectors [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and use the [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to convert the array. The [jQuery.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method will give the closest ancestor matching the given selector.

```
var cars = carsListTable.find('.table-data :checkbox:checked').map(function(i, v){
    return {
        ID : $(v).closest('tr').attr('carId')
    }
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2ERts/1/)

Note: The id of elements should be unique in a document so the `id` of the `checkbox` should be removed or has to be suffixed or prefixed by a dynamic value like the car id.

Comment: My VS 2012 Studio doesnt like the ID = syntax - it is saying should it be : (however I have tried this and my alerting my jsonString is still giving [] with your code above?

Comment: Cheers - I have used this and got it working - will mark as chosen. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use class instead id for elements that will be present more than once. I suggest change `#SelectIndividual` for `.SelectIndividual` on the checkbox input). Another thing you should change is the `carId` attribute, because is not semantic valid. You should use [custom data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead. This is how your code should look like:

#### HTML

```
@foreach (var car in Model.Cars)
{
    <tr data-carID="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.CarID)">
       <td class="table-data">
            <input id="SelectIndividual" name="Select" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
```

#### Jquery

```
$('#GetSelectedCars').click(function (event) {
    var cars= new Array();
    $('SelectIndividual:checked').each(function () {
        var car= new Object();
        car.ID = $(this).parent().parent().data('carID'); 
        cars.push(car);
    });
});
//keep doing things
```

Comment: Cheers - this was useful reponse also

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [data-*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attributes that are valid HTML5 as well as the jQuery[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) methods for the id of the car.

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign a class to all checkboxes in first column and then try this

```
$('.cbClass:checked').each(function () {
    tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    // use the row
})
```